# Excel Date function and Time function in one formula

Tags: excel

I have the following formula

```
DATE(YEAR(E687);MONTH(E687);DAY(E687))
```

and I want to use the `TIME` function as well. E.g:

```
DATE(YEAR(E687);MONTH(E687);DAY(E687)) - Time(10;0;0)
```

The reason is that I have guys working on my Excel sheetfrom **CAT** and **PST**
I am getting a date from the server and if a PST user adds data I want to minus 10 hrs from the server date to ensure I get the correct data in CAT.

I know my date above only shows date and not time but I want to remove 10hrs so see if it was done the previous day or the same day.

Comment: Other than the international formatting differences (using `;` instead of `,`), it works for me.

Comment: It appears that `E687` is a date.  That being the case, why not just `E687 - TIME(10;0;0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments on post suggests make sure your excels separation symbol e.g `;` or `,` - Check regional settings.

Worked!